# How can I make a multi select dynamic dependent to another multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Beginner here. How can I make a multi select dynamic dependent to another multiselect. The code below is for when a user select a single value and the values of the other select changes based on the value selected. What I want is when all values are selected the values will display all values of each.

```
 $("#value").change(function () {
 var user = $("#users_select").val();
        $('#value').empty();
        $('#value').append($("<option> </option>"));
        for (i = 0; i < jsonResult.length - 1; i++) {
          if (jsonResult[i]["value"] == user) {
            $('#tasks_select').append($("<option value="+jsonResult[i] 
         ["value"]+">" + jsonResult[i]["value"] + "</option>"));
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Please show your html, it might give us a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try like this:
$.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'url',
            type: "GET",
            data: {'id': id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var html = '';
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    html += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.selectname + '</option>';
                });
                $('#id' + count).html(html).select2();
            },
            error: function () {
            }

        });
```